# How to replace for loop with vectorization in numpy?

Tags: numpy-ndarray

Here is my function and I know for loop is slow 
There must be a faster/better way to do this in numpy

```
import numpy as np

def heat(u):
    my_u = np.empty_like(u)
    np.copyto(my_u, u)
    for row in range(1,u.shape[0]-1):
        for col in range(1,u.shape[1]-1):
            my_u[row, col] = (u[row-1][col] + u[row+1][col] 
            + u[row][col-1] + u[row][col+1])/4
    return my_u

print(heat(np.array([[100, 100, 100, 100, 100],
                    [100, 0, 0, 0, 100],
                    [100, 0, 0, 0, 100],
                    [100, 0, 0, 0, 100],
                    [100, 100, 100, 100, 100]])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you only want to add the 4 elements that is the cross, and not all neighbours? A search with '*sum neighbours numpy*' here on SO gives many answers for that which should work for you regardless of cross or complete set of neighbours by means of how you mask it.

If you want a small improvement in speed, ditch the double look-up of the array, that's around 30% quicker.

```
my_u[row, col] = (u[row-1, col] + u[row+1, col] 
                 + u[row, col-1] + u[row, col+1])/4
```

Comment: Yes, only 4 elements. Sorry, I don't understand where is the double look-up. I still cannot find an answer works for me